# A triple series evaluating to $\sqrt{3}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

How would you suggest me to approach the following triple series? I miss a starting point.

$$\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} (-1)^{i+j+k}\frac{1}{\displaystyle \sqrt{\left(i-\frac{1}{6}\right)^2+\left(j-\frac{1}{6}\right)^2+\left(k-\frac{1}{6}\right)^2}}=\sqrt{3}$$

Comment: is $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ defined as $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{-n}^{n}$?

Comment: I only ask because for infinite sums, it can matter a lot if the way you approach infinity changes, even if the terms are the same set of terms ...

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Say you consider $$\sum_{i=-n}^{n} \sum_{j=-n}^{n} \sum_{k= -n}^{ n} (-1)^{ i+ j+k}\frac{1}{\displaystyle \sqrt{\left(i- \frac{1}{ 6}\right)^2 +\left(j- \frac{1}{6}\right)^2 +\left( k-\frac{1}{ 6}\right)^2}}$$ and then set $n=50$, how do you compute the triple sum? For our case we let $n \to \infty$.

Comment: For $n=100$, Mathematica says the sum evaluates to $\approx 1.7378$.

Comment: @Chris'ssis How do you know this equals $\sqrt{3}$? Where did it come from?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee My brother gave it to me as a challenge (I don't know the real source of it).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18358/discussion-on-question-by-chriss-sis-a-triple-series-evaluating-to-sqrt3).

Comment: Some context would be needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main idea is to use the Mellin transform and a Jacobi product identity:
$$ \left( \sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}} (-1)^m q^{(3m^2+m)/2} \right)^3 = \sum_{n\geq 0} (-1)^n(2n+1) q^{(n^2+n)/2}. $$
This result is due to Forrester and Glasser (1982; *Some new lattice sums including an exact result for the electrostatic potential within the NaCl lattice*).

Set $q=e^{-2t/3}$ to get
$$ \sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}^3} (-1)^{|m|} e^{-\|m+\frac16\|^2t} = \sum_{n\geq0}(-1)^n(2n+1)e^{-\frac13(n+\frac12)^2t}, $$
where $|m|$ is the 1-norm and $\|m\|$ is the 2-norm.
If you multiply this by an arbitrary function $f$ whose Laplace transforms $\varphi(s)$ exists for all $s>0$, and integrate over $t\in[0,\infty)$, you get an identity that holds for every suitable Laplace transform $\varphi$:
$$ \sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}^3} (-1)^{|m|} \varphi\big(\|m+\tfrac16\|^2\big) = \sum_{n\geq0}(-1)^n(2n+1)\varphi\big(\tfrac1{3}(n+\tfrac12)^2\big). $$

Substituting $\varphi(s) = s^{-1/2} e^{-a\sqrt{s}}$, and performing the r.h.s. sum gives
$$ \sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}^3} \frac{(-1)^{|m|}e^{-a\|m+\frac16\|}}{\|m+\frac16\|} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\cosh \frac{a}{2\sqrt3}}. $$
The case $a=0$ is the one in your question. (Flip the sign $(i,j,k)\mapsto(-i,-j,-k)$ to get the right sign of $\frac16$.)

Comment: This solution is insane. Can this approach be used for other points in $\mathbb{Q}^3$ besides $(1/6, 1/6, 1/6)$?

Comment: If Chris's sister's brother's solution to this problem is similar to the one provided, I'd say it is quite a challenge.  Come on, either rediscover the equivalent of a 1982 result on lattice harmonics or search the literature for a hint.  All the literature.

Comment: @guest The starting point is [Madelung constants](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MadelungConstants.html).